# If the limit of Xn is cero.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

For all $n\geq N$ For all $n\geq N$For all $n\geq N$For all $n\geq N$For all $n\geq N$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to Robert Z's answer, you can prove it by contradiction:

Suppose for every $N$ you can find $n \geq N$ sucht that $X_n = 0$, then you can easily (by induction) extract a sequence $X_{\phi(n)}$ which is identically $0$, thus converges to $0$. But all extracted sequences of $(X_n)$ must converge to $a \neq 0$, absurd.

Comment: This is brilliant! Thanks =)

Answer (score 1):

By definition of limit, for $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{2}\|a\|>0$, there is $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for $n\geq N$, $|\|X_n\|-\|a\||\leq \|X_n-a\|<\varepsilon$  which implies that $\|X_n\|>\|a\|-\varepsilon=\frac{1}{2}\|a\|>0.$